# Fade and replace image with other image depending on hash

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

**First, here is my [crazy code](http://jsfiddle.net/b2550/R9cNW/) that you will hate**

So I have this image that I want to replace with a jQuery fade effect whenever the hash changes. I want for it to check the hash on onLoad too. Right now I have a crazy code that I am pretty sure doesn't work because I am a kind of new Javascript developer. It is a horrible code.

**If the code worked, it would do this:**

```
    //Home Hashes
var home = [
    "#home",
    "#news",
    "#team",
    "#cont",
    "#about",
    "#FAQ"];
```

It would check for for the hashes in each of these arrays, if it finds a match in one array, it will fade out the current image, switch them out, and fade the new image in. Depending on what array it is in, it will choose a different image.

*(BTW, when changing the image it is changing the src in the html.)*

I am using this to change my logo based on where you are on the site. My site has different logos for different sections.

Comment: It should be something like
`<img src="~/files/images/@if(hashdata == "#about") {about.png} else {home.png} alt="photo" />`  
I am assuming you use ASP.NET else, use the variables of conditions from your own server language.  
Secondly the hash tags are from JSON type array. I will assume you are using some JavaScript to read it. Well However you read it, doesn't matter Use jQuery to fade in and fade out
`$("this).fadeOut(); $("nextimage").fadeIn();`

Comment: I don't have ASP.NET sadly. I don't really follow what you are saying.

Comment: If you donot have ASP.NET then its not an issue. You can use PHP too. I was telling you about jQuery fadeIn and fadeOut.

Comment: How do I use PHP? Also, how do I use jQuery with that? Also how do I use multiple hashes?

Comment: Can anyone help me? I want to do this with Javascript if I can. PHP is fine.

Comment: You forgot to paste your HTML in your fiddle.

Comment: I ment to have not HTML at the moment.

Comment: I think people are having difficulty comprehending what it is you are after. Could you please describe the effect you are after as plainly as you can, without suggesting any implementation details? Are you just looking to use different logos depending on where you are on your site?

Comment: On the crazy code subject - some potential changes take a look at these fiddles: [Step1](http://jsfiddle.net/R9cNW/11/), [Step2](http://jsfiddle.net/R9cNW/12/), [Step3](http://jsfiddle.net/R9cNW/13/) **Not Tested**

Comment: @dc5 Thank you. Can you show me how to add the `if else` statement to the code below? I tried myself but couldn't get it to work.

Comment: @ChrisHardie The answer below should help you. It is a single page site that scrolls horizontally and vertically and my site has some different logos for each of the sections (viewport sized divs).

Comment: @dc5 Nevermind, I got it.

Comment: Wow, I can't get over the fact that my code was almost right and almost worked! I thought it was completely wrong! :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use onload plus hashchange

```
window.onload       = checkHash;
window.onhashchange = checkHash;

function checkHash() {
    // check stuff
}
```

Working Fiddle :: careful `hash` does change :-)

http://jsfiddle.net/R9cNW/9/

Comment: So I have only one question about this, how do I add an `if else` statement to check other arrays for the hash?

Comment: btw hashchange works on IE8 and up, be sure to check this site often for compatibilities for various things you would like to use: http://caniuse.com/#search=ha

Comment: I am not looking to add any IE support to my site. If someone visits my site with IE, it will come up with a message warning them and recommend a new browser. This is just my personal belief that IE is dumb, picky, and slow. ;)

Comment: IE9 and up are actually not that bad ..i just like my plugins and extensions

Comment: I have used it and still, I don't like the layout and it is still picky. I should do the same thing with firefox. Both are too picky.