# URL hash based slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/b2550/cjCfW/)
[Original Idea / Another version of this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18283017/fade-and-replace-image-with-other-image-depending-on-hash)

**Attention!**
*The other version of this idea/the original idea has been answered so if the other version works for you, your welcome :)*

*This question is still open*

So here is my new idea that I am having trouble with. I want to make an image slider. The slider has all the images inside of it and when the page turns to a hash like #home I want the slider to update to a new image. The slider is floating. The other thing is I don't want it to scroll passed other images. I just want it to scroll directly to that image. I also needs to scroll vertically since the images are different widths. I feel bad that I am basically making a job request so [this](http://jsfiddle.net/b2550/cjCfW/) is what I think is right. I can write the code if someone tells me what I need to do.

Here is the code on JS Fiddle. I just have the link so it can be worked on:

```
//This also need to execute when the hash is updated/an anchor link is clicked
window.onLoad = function hashLogo() {
var hash = window.location.hash;

//Image 1 Hashes
var image1 = [
    '#image1',
    '#home'
    ];

//Image 2 Hashes
var image2 = [
    '#image2',
    '#about'
    ];

if (image1.indexOf(hash) > -1) {
    //Do jQuery Sliding
}

if (image2.indexOf(hash) > -1) {
    //Do jQuery Sliding
}
};
```

Answer (score 0):

What I think you need is an event interception on the hashchange event:

```
$(window).hashchange( function(){
    // Do something when the hash changes
    // alert( location.hash );
});
```

If you also use Ben Alman's fabulous [hashchange plugin](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-hashchange-plugin/) (0.8kb), it will also ensure the event is polyfilled into browsers that don't support it.